# Forbidden icmp package between hosts?

Tags: icmp

I have 2 hosts, called client1 and client2, connected with a switch and this switch with another host called firewall, having access only with firewall.

Is it possible to forbid ping between clients?

Firewall have a dhcp server too, I don't know if dhcp server have an option for this.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can forbid that in a few ways. If your users are on different VLANs, you can impose the firewall between them, or a layer-3 switch could have an ACL between the VLANs. If you use something like a private VLAN, the users cannot communicate with each other.

In most cases, the users are on the same VLAN on a layer-2 switch, and you simply cannot control traffic between them because one host communicates directly to the other host via layer-2, and ICMP is a layer-3 protocol.